# While loop in shell script not working in the linux bash shell

Tags: linux, shell, csh

Am kind of newbie in writing shell scripts in linux. Its a `csh` script but am running it in the `bash` shell that why I used `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/csh`.

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 set i = 1
  3 echo it starts
  4 
  5 while ($i <= 5)
  6         echo i is $i
  7         @ i= $i +1
  8 end
```

**Note: ** The numbers are just to number the lines.

The above code gives me the output with error:

> ```
> it starts
> ./me.csh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
> ```

I can't figure out what is wrong even though it echos `it starts` and there is no line number 9 as specified in the error.

Comment: Your question tags, title and shebang says `bash`, but your script is `csh`. `bash` and `csh` are two different languages. Which language do you intend to write the script in?

Comment: I intend to write in `csh` but am running it from the `bash` shell

Comment: Frankly, I would encourage you to stack with bash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shebang must be set to the shell that should interpret the script. It doesn't matter which shell you run the script from. The only thing that matters is the language the script is written in.

Your script is written in `csh`, and must therefore have the shebang `#!/bin/csh`. This is true even if you want to run it from bash. Also, you were missing a space in your at-sign-ment:

```
$ cat me.csh
#!/bin/csh
set i = 1
echo it starts

while ($i <= 5)
        echo i is $i
        @ i = $i + 1
end
```

Output:

```
$ ./me.csh
it starts
i is 1
i is 2
i is 3
i is 4
i is 5
```

Comment: Thanks but am getting this error : `bash: ./me.csh: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` . And my using Kali linux and I don't know if it doesn't have `csh`.

Comment: If it doesn't have csh, you either have to install csh or rewrite your script into a language you *do* have support for.

Comment: I installed `csh` and now its working with `#!/bin/csh`. Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo it starts

i=1
while [ $i -le 5 ]; do
  echo i is $i
  i=$(( i+1 ))
done
```

Sample output:

```
it starts
i is 1
i is 2
i is 3
i is 4
i is 5
```

Here is a great reference:

[BASH Programming - Introduction HOW-TO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html#toc11)

Comment: Am sorry but maybe I wasn't more specific. I have edited my question.

Answer (score -1):

you should use Visual Studio Code with some extensions to check bash script syntax. I use Vscode in Window 10 WSL2 to run bash script.

change (...) to ((...)) to fix error syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=5

while ((a > 0)); do
    echo "a = $a"
    a=$((a - 1))
done
```